# Should I use different GTM container for Admin section of the web?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm working on a website that has two large sections:

- **"Frontend"** that is accessible for anyone on the internet (i.e. info about the product we offer, tutorials, blog, contact information, ..).
- **Administration** that is accessible only for registered and paying users. All admin pages URLs start with `/admin/`.

Both section will have standard Google Analytics pageview tracking code, but on the `/admin/` part I will also track a lot of other JS events.

Is it a best practise to

- *Use a different Google Tag Manager container on each section of the web (admin vs. non-admin)*.

**OR**

- Should I *use only one container and distinguish between the sections of the web using the filter Page Path starts with `/admin/` on all of the Admin events*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stick to a single container so that you don't need to set up different tags for each section of your site. However, in GA, I would probably set up a separate **view** for each section, and also a rollup view. You can easily use include filters to make sure you have one view containing only the front-end section, one for just the admin section, and finally one for everything (in addition to best practise views like Test and Raw).

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are some significant configuration differences in GTM between the 2, then just use the one. Otherwise you'll duplicate your workload as you administer changes.

You will still be able to distinguish the URL from where your visitors are anyway.